# not possible to get the enitre website using file_get_html/file_get_contents php code how to solve

Tags: php, curl

I  have tried this code but not getting the entire website

```
  $html=file_get_html('');
  echo $html;
```

Answer (score 2):

Js and Css location path is changing in your local server.

Its because file_get_contents dont "take" the javascript generated code.

I went into the website, and unabled the javascript in my browser, and the part you want dont appear.

You cant access this part like that, you will need to read all the ajax request to find where this information is stocked.

(and do the file_get_contents on those request).